# Android resource size qualifier

Tags: android, resources, qualifiers

I unable to get the values from "values-sw480dp" nor on my sony Xperia device which is 480 x 854 neither on Samsung galaxy tab which is 600 x 1024. But able to get on Motorola Xoom which is 1280 x 752.

*e.g  res/values-sw480dp/strings.xml/*

```
<string name="hello_world">hello world</string>
```

The values on respective devices

Sony Xperia ---->  @2131034113

Samsung   ---->   @2131034113

on xoom  ---> hello world

Can any one explain me this behavior, why Sony Xperia and Samsung has "@2131034113" value.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html, sw480dp means «smallest side of screen must be at least 480 dp». Now `dp` is a «pixel on a 160 dpi screen», so actual size of e.g. Xperia in `dp` would be I guess 320 x 569 (provided it's a hdpi device).

To get device screen size in `dp` you need to know abstracted density class (ldpi=120, mdpi=160, hdpi=240, xhdpi=320). For the above Xperia screen the calculation is: `(480*160/240) x (854*160/240)`, where 160 is the base density (it's where 1 `dp` actually equal to one pixel) and 240 is device abstracted density.

Comment: So as per above logic if I change sw480dp to sw320dp it should work on Xperia. Am I right?

Comment: Per above logic — yes; but keep in mind these "sw" qualifiers only work with Android level 13 (that's 3.2) and above.

Comment: Do we have any reference that tells "sw" qualifiers only works with Android level 13 or above. Thank you

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html says «Added in API level 13.» in the smallestWidth Description column.