# How to use screen size qualifiers when targeting multiple Android SDKs?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an app whose target SDK is version 8. Despite that, it must work in newer SDKs (Android 4.x, for example).

[This site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) says:

> The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific
>   resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts
>   for an extra large screen should go in layout-xlarge/.
>
> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are
>   deprecated and you should instead use the swdp configuration
>   qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your
>   layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout
>   requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in
>   layout-sw600dp/. Using the new techniques for declaring layout
>   resources is discussed further in the section about Declaring Tablet
>   Layouts for Android 3.2.

What is the best practice in my case? I do know how to handle SDK differences/deprecation when it is  about code (verify in runtime what OS version is running). But I don't know how to handle resources in this case.

Should I keep the old standard and use `layout-{small,normal,large,xlarge}` even with build target >= 13?

Should I change both `targetSdkVersion` and the project build target to something equal or greater than 13, keep `minSdkVersion` equals to 8 and use `layout-sw<N>dp`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting answer:
[Android resource size qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638518/android-resource-size-qualifier)
which leads to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html
where there is stated that layout-swdp was added on Android API level 13 (Android 3.2) so it's up to you whether you support lower versions, in this case you'll keep using layout-{small,normal,large,xlarge}.

So my answer is, go to the new standard in your case.

Here are general statistics to help you target your minimum version but you may look for more precise stats (limited to a country etc): http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html