# Smallest width dimension xml not getting called

Tags: android, android-layout

I am setting height property of an ImageView based on dimens.xml in the values folder. I have 1 dimens.xml for screens above sw480dp . But unfortunately all the times the default dimension file is getting called and not the sw480dp one . I tested this on a real device Samsung Note 2 running Android Lollipop . IDE used : Android Studio

[image]

```
                       <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgview"
                        android:layout_width="240dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

dimens.xml(default)

```
 <dimen name="image_size">250dp</dimen>
```

dimens.xml (sw480dp)

```
 <dimen name="image_size">500dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638518/android-resource-size-qualifier)

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html, sw480dp means «smallest side of screen must be at least 480 dp». Now dp is a «pixel on a 160 dpi screen», so actual size of Note 2 in dp would be I guess 724 dp x 451 dp (so not enougth to be provided as sw480dp).

Look also [here](http://mobilengineering.blogspot.it/2012/04/android-screen-densities-and-sizes-how.html)

And remember that "sw" qualifiers only work beginning from Android 3.2 (API level 13)